# Rails 3 uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery  

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid,  :with => :error_render_method
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found

  def error_render_method
  end

  def record_not_found
  end

end
```

When I run `rspec` I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (NameError)
```

I have googled and found that some people add `require 'active_record/errors'` to that file, yet when I do the error still persist.

I am using `rails (3.2.9)`

Comment: `require "active_record/validations.rb"` That's where the class is https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0034b7822d6132f5945b0514a5391d18e52aa4b6/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb That said, this should already be included and your code should work fine as it is

Comment: I tried your code on a newly created app under Rails 3.2.9. Worked fine w/o any `require`. Check your Gemfile, maybe you have some weird gem there?

Comment: The require statement that @injekt pointed worked. The strangest thing is that it only fails when running using rspec. If I use Spork, or run it on development, it just works.

Comment: Odd, perhaps spork loads `active_record/all`? I'm not entirely sure as I don't use either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem when I started Unicorn.

I solved it by just quoting the constant `"ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid"`.
(Not naked constant `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`.)

I don't know the reason but it seemed like `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` hadn't loaded when starting Unicorn.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been fixed between Rails 4.0 and 4.1.